# Understanding default gateways in the routing table

Tags: route, iproute

I have a wlan0 (wireless) and eth0 (ethernet), they are both dynamically assigned IP addresses through DHCP (connected to the same or different routers).
My route table looks like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth0
192.168.100.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 wlan0
```

I want to always prefer eth0 to be used over wlan0 when it is connected. I've tried adjusting the metric in the interfaces file but it doesn't seem to affect the metric shown in the routing table. I don't want to install ifmetric either.

So I manually tried to delete and add the default gateway using the route command (so that eth0 becomes at the top of the table) but it still seems to use wlan0 for the internet connection after doing so.

The only way it works now is if I actually disconnect and connect my wlan0, then eth0 will be used as default. The kernel seems to use the 'older' connection as the default.

Is there a way I can make eth0 to be the default always when available?

Thanks,